# Unable to find JQuery selector

Tags: jquery

I've an element

```
 <a ng-if="summaryData.secondFactorType == 'NOAUTH'" class="m-r-xl cursorPointer pull-right m-t-sm cancelbtn ng-scope" ng-click="cancel('PAY_NOAUTH') ">Cancel</a>
```

I want a selector to locate this element using `ng-click="cancel('PAY_NOAUTH')`

I'm unable to create proper selector because JQuery is giving syntax error one way or other

Comment: Why not find it by one of your classes?

Comment: @Taplar I guess `ng-click="cancel('PAY_NOAUTH')` may be more reliable and last more days than the classes

Comment: classes benifit from being able to fallback on the getElementsByClassName native selector which can have speed benifits over custom selectors.  When possible, try to use class or id selectors as much as possible.  the speed benifits may be unnoticable in some cases, but it will indeed to less work usually.  And if you ever decide to change your ng-click value, your logic won't break

Comment: Try this `$('a[ng-click="cancel(\'PAY_NOAUTH\')"]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you have a space after your ending parentheses, for me I needed to include the space in order for the selector to work or just remove the space from the html. This should work with the space

`$('a[ng-click="cancel(\'PAY_NOAUTH\') "]')`

and this without it

`$('a[ng-click="cancel(\'PAY_NOAUTH\')"]')`

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like this:

```
$("[ng-click='cancel(\"PAY_NOAUTH\")']")
```

Comment: It is giving error: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [ng-click='cancel('PAY_NOAUTH')']`

Comment: Did you escape the `'` around `PAY_NOAUTH` like above?

Comment: exactly same expression I'm entering in the chrome console.

Comment: Ok... Try it in console... Works for me `console.log($("[ng-click='cancel(\"PAY_NOAUTH\")']").length)`... I will edit about the quote change.